# Disable Save Button In Excel document loaded from vb.net

Tags: excel, vb.net

I am loading an Excel document using code like shown below:

```
Dim exApp As New Excel.Application
Dim exWB As Excel.Workbook = exApp.Workbooks.Add(Excel.XlWBATemplate.xlWBATWorksheet)
Dim exSheet As Excel.Worksheet
exSheet = exWB.ActiveSheet
```

Is there a way to disable the Save and Save as buttons for the generated document? So far, the only solutions I found involve writing into macros, but **this is not what I am after**. I need to be able to disable them from the vb.net application.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you try this code ?

```
AddHandler exWB.BeforeSave, AddressOf Workbook_BeforeSave

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)
    MsgBox("You are not enable to save.")
    Cancel = True
End Sub
```

Comment: As explained in my original post, I need to do it from the vb.net application, not from the document macro code.

Comment: @Osprey : That is possible through VB.NET code too (in this case both codes look the same). Just [**subscribe**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx) to your `exWB`'s [**`BeforeSave` event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff840057.aspx). -- https://i.stack.imgur.com/tsIsw.png

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent .I added the sub suggested in this answer to my vb.net code and then added `AddHandler exWB.BeforeSave, AddressOf Workbook_BeforeSave` but I am getting an error reading "Method 'Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(SaveAsUI As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)' does not have a signature compatible with delegate 'Delegate Sub WorkbookEvents_BeforeSaveEventHandler(SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)'."

Comment: @Osprey : Make the `Cancel` parameter `ByRef`: `Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(SaveAsUI As Boolean, ByRef Cancel As Boolean)`

Comment: @nbadaud : Please do that fix in your answer too.

Comment: Thanks @VisualVincent and nbadaud . It works perfectly now.